# SimpleInjector.ActivationException due to collection lifestyle

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I am trying to switch my DI container from Unity to SimpleInjector and I am struggling a bit with collections.

I have two concrete implementations of `IExceptionLogWriter` that I want to register as singletons so I do the following:

```
container.RegisterSingleton<RaygunExceptionLogWriter>();
container.RegisterSingleton<SqlExceptionLogWriter>();
```

Now I want to register both of those with a collection so I do this:

```
container
.RegisterCollection<IExceptionLogWriter>(
    new[] { 
        typeof(RaygunExceptionLogWriter), 
        typeof(SqlExceptionLogWriter) });
```

Now when I try run the application I get the following error:

> Additional information: A lifestyle mismatch is encountered. ExceptionLogger (Singleton) depends on IExceptionLogWriter[] (Transient). Lifestyle mismatches can cause concurrency bugs in your application. Please see https://simpleinjector.org/dialm to understand this problem and how to solve it.

If I understand the error correctly it looks like I need to somehow register `IExceptionLogWriter[]` as a singleton since I registered `RaygunExceptionLogWriter` and `SqlExceptionLogWriter` as singletons.  Maybe I am being dense but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do that.

I tried this:

```
container.RegisterSingleton<IExceptionLogWriter[]>();
```

That obviously crashed and burned.

**Edit - All Pertinent Registrations**

```
container.RegisterSingleton<SqlConnectionFactory>(new SqlConnectionFactory(connectionString));
container.RegisterSingleton<IApplicationExceptionRepository, SqlApplicationExceptionRepository>();
container.RegisterSingleton<IErrorHandler, ErrorHandler>();
container.RegisterSingleton<IExceptionLogger, ExceptionLogger>();
container.RegisterSingleton<RaygunExceptionLogWriter>();
container.RegisterSingleton<SqlExceptionLogWriter>();
container
.RegisterCollection<IExceptionLogWriter>(
    new[] { 
        typeof(RaygunExceptionLogWriter), 
        typeof(SqlExceptionLogWriter) });
```

And the related constructors:

```
public SqlConnectionFactory(string connectionString)
public SqlApplicationExceptionRepository(SqlConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
public ErrorHandler(IExceptionLogger exceptionLogger)
public ExceptionLogger(IExceptionLogWriter[] exceptionLogWriters)
public RaygunExceptionLogWriter()
public SqlExceptionLogWriter(IApplicationExceptionRepository applicationExceptionRepository)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening here is that your `ExceptionLogger` component has a constructor argument of type `IExceptionLogWriter[]` (an array of `IExceptionLogWriter`). Simple Injector automatically resolves array for you, but the implicit registration that Simple Injector makes is transient. The reason for this is that:

- An array is list of references. In case the list contains a component that is transient, injecting the array as singleton will cause [Captive Dependencies](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).
- An array is a mutable type; everybody can change the contents of the array. Making it singleton might cause unrelated parts of your applications to fail because of changes to the array.

So for safety reasons, Simple Injector makes the array registration transient. This allows the diagnostic system to kick in and warn you about any captive dependency it might cause.

The solution is simple and you have two options:

1. Make the `ExceptionLogger` consumer transient, or
2. Change `ExceptionLogger`'s dependency from `IExceptionLogger[]` to either `IEnumerable<IExceptionLogger>`, `IList<IExceptionLogger>`, `ICollection<IExceptionLogger>`, `IReadOnlyList<IExceptionLogger>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<IExceptionLogger>`.

For these collection abstractions Simple Injector will inject a collection that:

- Can't be changed from the outside, and
- Prevents captive dependencies by resolving an element according to its lifestyle every time the collection is iterated.

Comment: Thank you!  Do you have a link to where that is documented?  I thought I went through the documentation pretty well but I did not see anything like that.

Comment: @JasonBoyd: There are two parts of the documentation that discuss collections. Those are the [Using](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html) and the [how to](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#resolve-arrays-and-lists), but none of them explicitly state that arrays are created as transients. We might need to add this information to the docs.

Comment: Thanks.  I am a little surprised nobody has had questions about this before (maybe I really am dense).  When the project was originally started the parameter was `IEnumerable<IExceptionLogger>` but for Unity to work correctly it had to be changed to `IExceptionLogger[]`.  I would think anybody switching from Unity would bump into the same issue.  Well, I guess they would have to be switching from Unity and be registering everything as singletons - maybe that is less common.

Comment: @JasonBoyd: We actually have been asked this before, but we forgot to add the proper information to the docs. I've added [the information](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html#collections) now :).